# Android - AdMob to much CPU usage

Tags: android, admob, cpu-usage

Since I integrated the AdMob view on my app, the CPU usage of the app rose to 12% all the time, and the RAM rose 8mb too. What's appening?

Comment: if you add no code to your question nobody will be able to answer